# Background music notification with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-notifications

I have an application which plays music in the background and its notification is displayed in the notification center. Now, if I click on notification it should redirect me to the my composable screen and maintain its state like the music player seekbar should be in sync with my music notification player. I have used navigation compose for developing the app. How can I do it?

This is my MusicPlayer screen:

```
@Composable
fun MusicPlayerActivity(
    activity: NavigationActivity,
    navController: NavController,
    seekedValue: Float
) {
    val playerIcons by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.playerIcons) }
    val playerBackground by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.playerBackground) }
    val headerIcon by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.headerIcon) }
    val bannerTitle by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.bannerTitle) }
    val mainIcon by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.mainIcon) }
    val audioTitle by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.audioTitle) }
    val audioUri by remember { mutableStateOf(MusicPlayerData.audioUri.toString()) }
    val context = getLocalContext()
    val playerView by remember(context) { mutableStateOf(PlayerView(context)) }
    val seekProgress by remember { mutableStateOf(playerView.player?.currentPosition) }
    val playerService =
        rememberBoundLocalService<PlayerService, PlayerService.ServiceBinder> {
            this.playerService
        }
    val player = remember { playerService?.player }
    player?.prepare()
    player?.playWhenReady = false
    player?.seekTo(0, 0)
    val mediaMetaData = MediaMetadata.Builder()
        .setAlbumTitle(audioTitle)
        .build()
    val mediaItem =
        MediaItem.Builder().setMediaMetadata(mediaMetaData)
            .setUri(audioUri)
            .build()
    player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val (bg, header, mIcon, buttons, playerControl) = createRefs()
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .constrainAs(bg) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                },
            painter = painterResource(id = playerBackground!!),
            contentDescription = "",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )
        Header(
            leftIcon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ppp),
            rightIcon = painterResource(id = headerIcon!!),
            bannerTitle = bannerTitle, onClick = {
                if (it) {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(header) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
        )
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(50.dp)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .constrainAs(mIcon) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                },
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(mainIcon),
            contentDescription = "",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .constrainAs(buttons) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(playerControl.top)
                }) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .noRippleClickable {
                        activity.isRewindClicked.value = true
                        playerView.player?.seekTo(0)
                    },
                painter = painterResource(id = rewind),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .noRippleClickable {
                        playerView.player?.pause()
                    },
                painter = painterResource(id = pause),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .noRippleClickable {
                        playerView.player?.play()
                    },
                painter = painterResource(id = play),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .noRippleClickable {
                        playerView.player?.pause()
                    },
                painter = painterResource(id = stop),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
        DisposableEffect(AndroidViewBinding(
            factory = MusicPlayerBinding::inflate,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(playerControl) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }
        ) {
            this.controls.player = player
            playerView.player = player
            if (seekProgress != null)
                playerView.player?.seekTo(seekProgress!!)
        }) {
            onDispose {
                player?.release()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
inline fun <reified BoundService : Service, reified BoundServiceBinder : Binder> rememberBoundLocalService(
    crossinline getService: @DisallowComposableCalls BoundServiceBinder.() -> BoundService,
): BoundService? {
    val context: Context = getLocalContext()
    var boundService: BoundService? by remember(context) { mutableStateOf(null) }
    val serviceConnection: ServiceConnection = remember(context) {
        object : ServiceConnection {
            override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
                boundService = (service as BoundServiceBinder).getService()
            }

            override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
                boundService = null
            }
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(context, serviceConnection) {
        val intent = Intent(context, PlayerService::class.java)
        context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        onDispose { context.unbindService(serviceConnection) }
    }
    return boundService
}
```

This is my service class:

```
class PlayerService : Service() {

    private val iBinder = ServiceBinder()
    var player: Player? = null
    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null
    lateinit var notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager

    inner class ServiceBinder : Binder() {
        fun getPlayerService(): PlayerService = this@PlayerService
    }


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return iBinder
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession =
            MediaSession.Builder(this, player!!).setSessionActivity(pendingIntent()!!)
                .setId(Random(5).toString())
                .build()
        notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, 111, "Music Channel")
            .setChannelImportance(IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.music)
            .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.app_name)
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.app_name)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(audioDescriptor)
            .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
            .build()


        notificationManager.setPlayer(player)
        notificationManager.setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
        notificationManager.setUseRewindAction(true)
        notificationManager.setUseFastForwardAction(false)
        notificationManager.setUsePreviousAction(false)
        notificationManager.setUsePlayPauseActions(true)
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (player?.isPlaying!!) {
            player?.stop()
        }
        notificationManager.setPlayer(null)
        player?.release()
        player = null
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private val notificationListener = object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
        override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
            super.onNotificationCancelled(notificationId, dismissedByUser)
            stopForeground(true)
            if (player?.isPlaying!!) {
                player?.stop()
                player?.release()
            }
        }

        override fun onNotificationPosted(
            notificationId: Int,
            notification: Notification,
            ongoing: Boolean
        ) {
            super.onNotificationPosted(notificationId, notification, ongoing)
            startForeground(notificationId, notification)
        }
    }

    private val audioDescriptor = object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
        override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
            return player.currentMediaItem?.mediaMetadata?.albumTitle!!
        }

        override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
            return pendingIntent()
        }

        override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence? {
            return ""
        }

        override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
            player: Player,
            callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
        ): Bitmap? {
            val bitmapDrawable: BitmapDrawable =
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    applicationContext,
                    R.drawable.cma_logo_render
                ) as BitmapDrawable
            return bitmapDrawable.bitmap
        }
    }

    private fun pendingIntent(): PendingIntent? {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, NavigationActivity::class.java).putExtra("navigate",true)
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }
```

I am setting the pending intent to my original activity only from where I am managing navigation in compose.

Now in MusicPlayer I have set some variables as remember, but I don't know. How will it redirect to me on the MusicPlayer composable screen in the same state?

Activity from where all composables will be called and the player instance is initialized from the service:

```
class NavigationActivity : ComponentActivity(), ItemClickListInterface {

    var player: Player? = null
    val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()
    var musicPlayerData = MusicPlayerData
    var isServiceBound = false
    var isRewindClicked = mutableStateOf(false)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    private fun bindMusicService() {
        isServiceBound = true
        val intent = Intent(this, PlayerService::class.java)
        bindService(intent, playerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    private val playerServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            val binder = service as PlayerService.ServiceBinder
            player = binder.getPlayerService().player!!
            player?.prepare()
            player?.playWhenReady = false
            player?.seekTo(0, 0)
            val mediaMetaData = MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .setAlbumTitle(MusicPlayerData.audioTitle)
                .build()
            val mediaItem =
                MediaItem.Builder().setMediaMetadata(mediaMetaData)
                    .setUri(MusicPlayerData.audioUri)
                    .build()
            player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            setPlayerControls()
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

    private fun setPlayerControls() {
        player?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                        loginViewModel.loading.value = true
                    }
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        if (isRewindClicked.value) {
                            isRewindClicked.value = false
                            player?.playWhenReady = true
                        } else {
                            player?.playWhenReady = false
                        }
                        loginViewModel.loading.value = false
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                        player?.seekTo(0)

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (isServiceBound) {
            isServiceBound = false
            unbindService(playerServiceConnection)
            if (player?.isPlaying!!) {
                player?.stop()
            }
            player?.release()
            player = null
        }
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    @Composable
    fun NavigationComponent(navController: NavHostController) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("navigate")) {
            navController.navigate(Screens.MusicPlayer.route)
        }
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
            composable(Screens.MusicPlayer.route) {
                bindMusicService()
                MusicPlayerActivity(
                    activity = this@NavigationActivity,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

In service class

```
    private fun pendingIntent(): PendingIntent? {
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                ("music://music_player_screen/" + player?.currentPosition).toUri()
            )
        )
        return getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<activity
            android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="music" android:host="music_player_screen" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

inside navhost controller

```
composable(Screens.MusicPlayer.route + "/{seekedValue}",
                deepLinks = listOf(
                    navDeepLink {
                        uriPattern =
                            "music://music_player_screen/{seekedValue}"
                    }
                ), arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("seekedValue") { type = NavType.FloatType }
                )) {
                val isServiceBound =
                    runBlocking { dataStoreManager.dataStore.data.first() }[Constant.PreferenceKeys.isServiceBound]
                        ?: false
                if (!isServiceBound) {
                    bindMusicService()
                }
                MusicPlayerActivity(
                    activity = this@NavigationActivity,
                    navController = navController,
                    seekedValue = it.arguments?.getFloat("seekedValue")!!
                )
            }
```

Comment: Just post the logic you in use to maintain the state in the notification. Also post the notification builder here. I'll let you know.

Comment: I'm sure I added a comment here. It's not here anymore. My question was, you are initializing a `PlayerView()` instance inside an `@Composable` scope without using any `remember`ing logic. So, does it not randomly reset the player every now and then? Like when you close the app by pressing the home button and get back? Post the `PlayerView()` code too, please.

Comment: I am initializing playerview here inside composable     val playerView = PlayerView(getLocalContext())

Comment: It works and it doesn't resets the player randomly

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. The recommended option is to use deep links. Take the Navigation Codelabs, specifically [enabling deep link support](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#7) to learn in detail. Sample implementation:

Firstly, within your `Manifest`, add the deep link filter:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="musify" android:host="musicPlayerScreen" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Replace 'musify' with the name of your app, and 'musicPlayerScreen' with the value of `Screens.MusicPlayer.route`. You didn't post the code for that so I didn't know the value of the route here.

In your `NavHost`,

```
composable(
route = "${Screens.MusicPlayer.route}/{seekedValue}", // Append a value argument
arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("seekedValue") { type = NavType.FloatType }
    ),
deepLinks = listOf(
       navDeepLink { uriPattern = "musify://${Screens.MusicPlayer.route}/{seekedValue}"}
    )
) {
  bindMusicService() // Not a good place to call this, I think.
  MusicPlayerActivity(
    activity = this@NavigationActivity,
    navController = navController,
    seekedValue = it.arguments?.getFloat("seekedValue") // retrieve the value here
  )
}
```

Now, modify the `MusicPlayer` to accept a third parameter, as shown above, called `value`. At the top of the Composable, set the seeker value to the incoming parameter.

Now, wherever you navigate to this music screen from, you'll need to provide a separate argument, representing the initial seeked value. If you'd rather not, you can also set a default value (of 0, or anything) to your arguments. Anyway, all the setup is done, for the major part.

Now, all that is left is to call the deep link from your service. The only way to launch an activity or pretty much any external task from a `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` is to fire an `Intent`. So, equip your intent with the deeplink pattern reated/specified in the Manifest earlier, and launch it upon the user clicking your notification.

Within your notification builder,

```
notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, 111, "Music Channel")
            .setChannelImportance(IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.music)
            .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.app_name)
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.app_name)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(audioDescriptor)
            .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)

          // Here
            .setContentIntent( // Fired on Interaction
              Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("musify://musicPlayerScreen/${player.currentPosition}"))
             )
            .build()
```

That's it, you should be able to flawlessly navigate to the Composable.

The second approach I was referring to was a bit rough. That was to just pass the value along with the intent to the activity as an `extra`, then reading the value from the intent at the start of `onCreate`, or `onResume` and reflecting it.

Comment: don't forget to make a backup of the original codebase before doing any refactoring!

Comment: yes sure. Thanks will update if this works for me.

Comment: My bad, there is no dollar sign in navhost argument for the deep-link. It is just `seekedValue`, not `$seekedValue`. It will be non-functional if you don't remove the sign, since it modifies the name of the link's nav argument. It's complicated to explain here but trust me the dollar sign won't be there.

Comment: I tried this way but when I click on notification it is taking me to my start destination which is splash screen right now and after it follows the app navigation flow normally. It doesn'e navigates to MusicPlayer composable screen

Comment: You sure you properly replaced names in my answer with your own app-specific names? Also, you must read the docs I linked. It's essential in understanding nevigation and deep links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247578/discussion-between-primo-and-richard-onslow-roper).

Comment: I figured out I missed somehting and somehow I was able to navigate to music player screen on click of notification. But as you can see I have bind my xml layout for seekbar and timers of exoplayer and they are not getting updated. What to add in to make it work?

Comment: That's what the seeker values that I added to the Composable are for.

Comment: You need to manually set the player value equal to the parameter that you received. Read again. I told you, a new parameter is required inside MusicPlayer Composable. I don't see that parameter in the code you have posted above. Update the code for the MusicPlayer Composable.

Comment: I checked it and the instance which I am using in music player composable  activity.player is returning null when I come on click of notification

Comment: Please post the code of the Composable `MusicPlayerActivity`.

Comment: I have updated the code for same

Comment: Buddy how can you expect the value to be reflected when you're not even using it in your composable? You are initializing `seekProgress` with the default progress of the player. You have to set the progress to the `seevedValue` parameter that I had you create. That's why I asked you to read the solution again. I specifically mentioned -- "At the top of the Composable, set the seeker value to the incoming parameter."

Comment: Also, it should not be `player.seekTo(0, 0)`. Use the incoming parameter to set the seek progress. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: I updated this line player.seekTo(0, 0) with player.seekTo(seekedValue.toLong()). But unfortunately I am getting seekedValue as 0

Comment: This means you are not passing it correctly. It is defaulting to 0, because that's what we programmed it to do. Or, your seeker implementation always returns 0

Comment: In the calling intent, you have to pass the current progress of the notification player, which I denoted by `player.value`. Of course, you need to change it to the appropriate call, like `player.currentPosition()`, as our seems in your case.

Comment: yes I did that only.. Passed player.currentPosition

Comment: I figured out. I was getting the seekedvalue but it was less than 0 that's why it was not having any effect. But now I am confused how will I get the correct progress of musicplayer

Comment: Maybe it is inverted because of some implementation fault. Try negating it, and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, after searching and encapsulating the answers from different sources with yours, I was able to do it. But still facing problems, first is whenever I click on notification, my service gets destroyed and then recreates. Secondly, whenever this line is called player.seekTo(0, 0), then screen goes in infinite navigation loop. Do you have any answers to these problems?

Comment: Please elaborate on the infinite navigation loop. It is likely because of the `addNextIntentWithParentStack`.

Comment: infinte loop means screens gets called again and again... pending intent gets fired again and again and thus ends up calling navigation grpah again and again

Comment: If using addNextIntentWithParentStack is causing the problem what is the solution to this?

Comment: Where are you using the method `pendingIntent()`?

Comment: It is used in service class when we set notification in audioDescriptor

Comment: Hard to diagnose the problem without having an active debugging session. Plus, it wasn't me who wrote it so it'll take time even if I had the entire project to play with. Do you have a git set up?

Comment: no, I don't have git setup

Comment: Can't process the codebase without the codebase, you see? Just set up a GitHub account, it is free forever. Upload the codebase to it. Once you setup the account, and login with the same email address in Android Studio, you can upload automatically from studio as well.

Comment: I think val player by rememberUpdatedState(playerService?.player) is getting called multiple times even when the music screen is called for the first time and this is creating problem later also.

Comment: Can you give me 1 solution? Whenever I click on music notification, my service gets destroyed. If by any way we can prevent it from getting destroyed then all things will work